# taking argument from comprehensions list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I take an argument from this list so that I can put it in place of a phone?

```
a10 = ' ' * (2 + length)+ (' ' * length - len(str(phone))).join([str(x) for x in range(1, boardX + 1)])
```

The idea is that `(' ' * length - len(str(phone)))` determine the space between numbers depending on whether the number is one digit, two digit, etc.
In the phone place I would like to take an argument from a list to specify the number of its characters. –

example:
boardX = 14
length = 3

output:

[image: output]

target output:

[image: target output]

Comment: Please specify what do variables such as length, phone and boardX refer to as well.

Comment: what are you even trying to do exactly? from the start, what is your idea of what this code will do, what will be input and output ([edit] question and add all the necessary information, samples as well as a [mre])

Comment: Don't do it this way. Use a formatting function, they allow you to specify the field width and they'll automatically add padding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formatting operator rather than calculating spaces yourself. Yo can specify the field width indirectly using `*`.

```
a10 = " " * (2 + length) + "".join("%*d" % (length, x) for x in range(1, boardX + 1))
```